BOINC ownership or permissions are not set properly error on Mac
I got the following error every time when I try to run BOINC the second time, when ATLAS LHC@Home running, which uses VirtualBox. (So first it launches corrertly, then second times fails.)

BOINC ownership or permissions are not set properly; please reinstall
BOINC. (Error code -1202 at /Library/Application Support/BOINC
Data/projects/virtualbox)

I'm on Mac Sonoma 14.6.1, BOINC version 8.0.2.
I tried to give permission on the mentioned folder to all, but it didn't solved the issue.
Reinstall "reset" the issue, meaning it starts over. (First time fine, then fails.)
